# How is this site moderated for exclusion of and ousting of people?

Tags: support, specific-question, questions, close-reasons, moderation

I would like to know how contrast about who should win an election, who is the one out, and who holds a view that is not eligible to stand, is dealt with on this site. Perhaps, it is the role of moderators (who, are, for sure, voted). Can you please help me with addressing this issue? Thanks

Comment: tags [specific-question], [questions], [close-reasons] should be removed and you should add the [election] and [moderators] tags

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you are asking here. The first sentence makes no sense to me. Can you try to rephrase the question? You also picked various tags which don't make a lot of sense. For example, you picked "specific-question", but you did not link to any specific question. This confuses me even more.

Comment: Are you asking if certain political-perspectives might bar a user from being elected as a moderator?

Comment: @Nat I think they might be asking if people with certain political views get ousted from this site. But I would like a confirmation before I answer that.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding elections, similarly to other sites on the Stack Exchange Network,

##### Q: who should win an election, who is the one out?

> Each community member gets one vote, with which they rank the candidates in order. Votes are tallied using the Meek STV method; to understand how STV works, see this video. Each voter can select the candidate they most want, and also specify additional choices of candidates they prefer should their top choice candidate not receive enough votes, in order of their preference. These additional choices may also receive partial votes if a voter's top choice wins and receives more votes than the threshold required to win.
>
> -- *[There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360)*

##### Q: (how are those) who holds a view that is not eligible to stand, is dealt with?

Election results all depend on the votes (or lack of) from the community members who are eligible to vote. Moderators get to vote since they are also community members.

If you have a more specific question regarding "a view that is not eligible" - please provide examples.

Do note that any user who has been suspended anywhere on the network within the past 365 days are not eligible to nominate themselves in an election, and their nominations will be manually removed by the community managers.

If you think a appointed/elected moderator should be removed, the process to initiate a review is detailed here: *[What processes exist to issue formal warnings or remove moderators?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336173)*